# Asp.net Mvc Bundles и Gzip

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, gzip

Проблема следующего характера:

Сервер не отдает `Content-Encoding:gzip` для бандлов с Javascript. С бандлами с CSS все впорядке. На локальном сервере(IIS/8.5) проблему решил путем включения сжатия динамического контента и еще пары настроек, а вот на боевом (IIS/7.5) ну никак не включается.

Answer (score 2):

вот в этой статейке всё подробно расписано: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/05/Builtin-GZipDeflate-Compression-on-IIS-7x

посмотрите свой web.config на наличие: `<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />`

проверить строку в файле конфигурации IIS applicationHost.config:

```
<section name="httpCompression" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

Вот это `overrideModeDefault="Deny"` надо убрать, иначе через web.config не будет работать.
Надо заменить на:

```
<section name="httpCompression" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Comment: Все это настроено и на локальном и на боевом, только вот на локальном все работает а на боевом нет. Может что нибудь блокировать это кроме IIS`a?

Comment: посмотрите внимательно applicationHost.config на вашем боевом IIS 7.5 и сравните его с локальным